# Want to compare two columns in excel

Tags: excel, countif

Hi I want to compare two columns in Excel.

I know to use CountIf to set up a basic comparison for 1 value.

The following will compare all values in a named 'B' column with all values of Column 'A'

=COUNTIF(secondList,A`)=0

What I need to do is to figure out how to compare both columns to see if the value in cell A1 equals the value in Cell B1,; the value in A2 equals the value in B2, ... etc.

How do I do that?

[image]

Comment: What should the result be - the number of times the values are equal, or not equal?

Comment: not equal. When I use Conditional Formatting I want the cell pairs to highlight in yellow if they don't match.

Comment: Then use the formula `=$A1<>$B1` and apply it to columns A and B.

Comment: So =COUNTIF(secondList,A)=$A1<>$B1 or =COUNTIF(secondList,=$A1<>$B1)=0?

Comment: No COUNTIF at all, just that simple formula.

Comment: It works but what I'm trying to do is have the pair of cells that don't match highlighted in yellow. I've pasted an example of my desired output above. I'm trying to do this using conditional formatting.

Comment: That formula works with conditional formatting, I'm not sure I follow: https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q3AsR.png

Comment: You're right. That did it.  Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

If you want conditional formatting, then just use a rule based on the formula:

```
=$A1<>$B1
```

[image]: